# JavaEE EJB injection cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, dependency-injection, ejb

I set up an Enterprise Application Project with two modules: an EJB Project and a Web Project.
The web project contains a servlet in which I want to inject an EJB from the EJB Project.
The former looks like this:

```
@WebServlet("/OutputServlet")
public class OutputServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@EJB
UserEJB userejb;

.
.
.
```

And the latter like this:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserEJB {

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public UserEJB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
.
.
.
```

The "UserEJB" part in the line `UserEJB userejb;` is marked as faulty in eclipse, with the message that UserEJB cannot be resolved to a type.
It might be worth mentioning that I am running all this on Wildfly 10.0

Here is the application.xml of the Application Project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" id="Application_ID" 
version="7">
  <display-name>SecondTest</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>SecondEJB.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>SecondWeb.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>SecondWeb</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently eclipse does not add the EJB Project to the build path automatically. Doing it fixes the problem